# Flying saucer - Second page has not the height from the header

Tags: css, flying-saucer

I´m trying to generate from HTML a PDF in Flying Saucer. At the end I would like to have something like an invoice.

I´m also using JSF / Primefaces to generate HTML code.
My generateHtmlCodeController function is generating plain HTML code.

Maybe a little bit more background: I have a designer, which is generating my template. All template settings are stored in a XML file. On rendering time the XML file will be loaded and is generating based on that the HTML code (generateHtmlCodeController). All this is already implemented and it´s working.

The main issue is with Flying Saucer and overlapping tables.

Here is my current JSF code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet>

     @page{
        size: A4 portrait;

         @top-center { 
            content: element(header) 
         }
         @bottom-center { 
            content: element(footer) 
         }

      }

        div.header {
            display: block; text-align: center; 
            position: running(header);
        }
        div.footer {
            display: block; text-align: center;
            position: running(footer);
        }

      table {
        -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
        -fs-page-sequence: auto;
        border-spacing: 0;
        page-break-after:auto;
      }

      thead {
        display: table-header-group;
      }
      tfoot {
        display: table-header-group;
      }


    </h:outputStylesheet>
    <title>Vorschau</title>
</h:head>

<h:body class="main">

    <section> <ui:repeat
        value="#{previewDocumentDesignerController.editablePageList}"
        var="templatePage" varStatus="templatePageStatus">


         <div class="header">
            <ui:repeat value="#{templatePage.editableElementHeaderList}"
            var="editableElement" varStatus="status">

                <div style="position: absolute; top: #{editableElement.top/100 * 21}cm; left: #{editableElement.left/100 * 21}cm;width: #{editableElement.width/100 * 21}cm;height: #{editableElement.height/100 * 29.7 - 0.2}cm;">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{generateHtmlCodeController.generateHtmlCode(editableElement)}"
                        escape="false" />
                </div>

            </ui:repeat>
        </div>



         <div class="content">
            <ui:repeat value="#{templatePage.editableElementContentList}"
                var="editableElement" varStatus="status">

                <div style="position: absolute; top: #{editableElement.top/100 * 21}cm; left: #{editableElement.left/100 * 21}cm;width: #{editableElement.width/100 * 21}cm;height: #{editableElement.height/100 * 29.7 - 0.2}cm;">
                    <h:outputText
                        value="#{generateHtmlCodeController.generateHtmlCode(editableElement)}"
                        escape="false" />
                </div>

            </ui:repeat>
        </div>



         <div class="footer">
            <ui:repeat value="#{templatePage.editableElementFooterList}"
                var="editableElement" varStatus="status">

                <div style="position: absolute; top: #{editableElement.top/100 * 21}cm; left: #{editableElement.left/100 * 21}cm;width: #{editableElement.width/100 * 21}cm;height: #{editableElement.height/100 * 29.7 - 0.2}cm;">
                 <h:outputText
                    value="#{generateHtmlCodeController.generateHtmlCode(editableElement)}"
                    escape="false" /> 
                </div>

            </ui:repeat>
        </div>


    </ui:repeat> 
</section>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the output from my first page:

[image]

Please see here the second page (with the issue)

[image]

Comment: Here also in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/kbjrJxEB

Comment: I only see html here nothing JSF and/or PrimeFaces related. And you can edit questions for adding code, but code should be inline in the question in [mcve] flavour. And this question is not openhtmltopdf related.. You are not using it now...

Comment: oh and footers/headers work for me flyingsaucer.

Comment: I cannot paste pastebin link in my question? here is the JSF code: https://pastebin.com/kFCfeSU3

Comment: No the actual code should, in [mcve] format be posted inline...

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow me to post all the code which is needed to reproduce it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, reduce the code... Most likely it is not a [mcve] then. max 20 lines of java code for the real call to xhtmlrenderer and max 20 lines  in java to produce the related html would be sufficient in a [mcve]. I'm sure that is possible (I did it in unit tests)

Comment: I´ve updated my question to be more specific. I hope somebody can help